# Cleaning a filename after image sideloading a url that contains `%20`

Tags: plugin-development, images, uploads, import, filesystem

Right now I'm creating a plugin to sideload images from an external source.

The UI allows me to select files on the external server then downloads them via AJAX & [`media_sideload_image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image).  Everything is working great. After the images is loaded I clean up the attachment's title by replacing the dashes and underscores with spaces in addition to separating alpha/numerics for legibility.

```
// sideload the image
$src = media_sideload_image(esc_url($url), $post_id, $desc, $return);

// convert to attachment src -> ID -> post
$id = attachment_url_to_postid($src);
$post = get_post($id);

// clean the title
// BEFORE: BB-SH-YongKang20Road-6
// AFTER: BB SH YongKang 20 Road 6

$title = $post->post_title;
$title = str_replace('-', ' ', $title);
$title = str_replace('_', ' ', $title);
$title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", "", $title);
$title = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $title);
```

My problem is the random `20` which I know is because of an encoded space `%20`. Now all titles and filenames have this random 20.

How can I clean the source url and still make it valid or modify the final filename to exclude `%20`/`20`?

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

```
$src = media_sideload_image(rawurldecode($url), $post_id, $desc, $return);
```

Comment: I think you want `esc_url_raw` so the input URLs aren't html encoded.

Comment: At first blush I didn't see any change. I'll test more to make sure because this seems like a good idea.

Comment: `rawurldecode` is the only one that worked and I can't see any change with `esc_url_raw`. Is there a way to make sure the url is clean if it's decoded? I don't imagine the external url can be tampered with but I'm not a security expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) fixes the issue.

```
$src = media_sideload_image(rawurldecode($url), $post_id, $desc, $return);
```